# Como usar Genymotion para flutter no vs code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

Queria saber como eu posso emular os apps do flutter no vs code com o genymotion pois sempre quando dou o flutter doctor ele aparece que nao tem dispositivos

não consigo achar nenhum tutorial na inter de como instalar os dois, mas vejo que é possivel

````
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.17763.973], locale pt-BR)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available```
````

Comment: Seu Android Studio está instalado corretamente? Pela mensagem no doctor do flutter aparentemente não está. Resolva os problemas ligados a ele e garanta que não foi detectado nenhum problema com o SDK do Android no seu computador. Já utilizei sem problemas o Genymotion para desenvolvimento e não foi necessário nenhuma configuração adicional para isso.

Comment: mas não existe alguma forma de usar apenas o vs code e o genymotion? sem o android studio?

Comment: Seu objetivo é programar aplicativos Flutter e emular no Genymotion não é? Sendo assim o primeiro passo é instalar todo o ambiente do `Flutter` que tem incluso o Android Studio. É recomendado instalá-lo pela facilidade de instalar o SDK já que vem integrado no AS, caso contrario teria que instalar o SDK separadamente que é bem mais trabalhoso. Eu recomento que monte o básico do seu ambiente primeiro e deixe a parte da emulação para o final. Se a base estiver ok vai ajudar a identificar problemas específicos depois.

Comment: Para utilizar o genymotion, configure o caminho do SDK dele para o mesmo caminho do SDK utilizado pelo Flutter. Se você utiliza o Android Studio, pode pegar lá o caminho do SDK utilizado nele.